# Flash video working on one of two sites in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I am developing a pair of websites (podyplomie.pl and magwet.pl).

On both of them we have added a video player (JWPlayer).

I am almost sure flash player on both of them was working in the beginnig but now I can play the video (in flash) only on one of the sites (podyplomie.pl).

The other site is missing flash player in the list of `navigator.plugins`. Both sites are very similar so it's quite strange that one of them 'contains' the flash player and the second doesn't.

Has anyone got an idea what is wrong ?

The video urls are eg:

[Video on magwet.pl](https://magwet.pl/filmy/films/4065)

[Video on podyplomie.pl](https://podyplomie.pl/medVOD/films/3327)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any Flash video (`.FLV`). Your videos are in `.MP4` format. Chrome browser can play MP4 with it's own decoding engine (no need for plugins like Flash). JW Player is seeing MP4 given as video source so it talks to browser not plugin...

PS: To force Flash plugin usage then provide an `.flv` file or `rtmp://` link.

Comment: There are rtmps links in the sources list. JWPlayer loads flash version when it is not able to play the HTML5 movie (which happens correctly on podyplomie.pl, not on magwet.pl).

The problem is that Chrome does not see the Flash Player in the plugins list on magwet.pl (and can see it on podyplomie.pl).

Comment: (1) At magwet.pl, can you make a basic test page (just player with only RTMP url in playlist) to recreate your _"..When it is not able to play the HTML5 movie"_? Otherwise your MP4 is always working (and why not?) so for now it plays only via HTML5 not Flash. Test page can be deleted later. (2) Also your Playlist has MP4 as third option after 1st `.m3u8` and 2nd `rtmp://` sources, the third item is what my Chrome plays when I visit the page. JW skipped the 2nd (Flash) and went to 3rd (MP4) in playlist. Is that expected?

Comment: The problem isn't with the player/player configuration but the plugins that are seen by the browser - on podyplomie.pl when I enter the site the `navigator.plugins` contains the Flash player. On magwet.pl **Flash player is not on the list of plugins** (and is skipped as the video source by JWPlayer). That is probably why the player is skipping the second source on the list of files. What might be the reason ?